# Miter gears with straight or spiral teeth has the least or almost zero backlash?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

For small gears of about 20-32mm of OD, which type has the least or almost zero backlash? Miter Gears with straight teeth or with spiral teeth? Do the mounting distance and shaft diameter have an effect on the backlash?

Comment: I don't see any reason why one would have less backlash than the other.

Answer (score 4):

Gears you listed do not have zero backlash. The backlash in all cases is about the same. Mounting distance affects backlash the same way in all the cases you outlined, having right distance from backlashes point of view is critical. (Since the geometry at any infinitesimal slice is the same for all these gears)

If you need a backlash free transmission then you either need to have a spring tension on the gear to keep it constantly at other side of the gear. This strategy is used in dial indicators. Or use a transmission that does not inherently have backlash like strain wave gears.

Comment: "dail" should be "dial".